# How do I echo multiple values from a PHP file to a Javascript Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

With reference to the code attached below, I wish to reference variables which have been initialized in my processUsersAnswers.php, in my index.php file.

Code snippet in **index.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function checkAnswers(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    /* code */

    xhr.open("POST", "processUsersAnswers.php", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            /* code */
        }
    }
    xhr.send(vars); // 
}
```

Code snippet in **processUsersAnswers.php**

```
<?php 
$score = 403;
$userAnswers = array();
$userAnswers[0] = "bla bla";
$userAnswers[1] = "asfasfaeg";
$userAnswers[2] = "erhehdfh";

/*How can I retrieve $userAnswers in my index.php file? */
?>
```

For instance, how can I retrieve the value for $score in my index.php file?

Comment: With simple `echo`

Comment: Try: `echo $score`

Comment: But there are many variables. Could you be a bit clearer.

Comment: Did you solve your problem ?

Comment: Yes, I echoed out a string which separates the elements with a comma and then created a function which interprets the string as an array. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Your new `processUsersAnswers.php` file

```
<?php 
$score = 403;
$userAnswers = array();
$userAnswers[0] = "bla bla";
$userAnswers[1] = "asfasfaeg";
$userAnswers[2] = "erhehdfh";

echo json_encode('score' => $score);
exit;
```

And in your JS :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkAnswers(){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        /* code */

        xhr.open("POST", "processUsersAnswers.php", true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                alert(json.score);
            }
        }
        xhr.send(vars); // 
    }
```

This is not mandatory to use JSON, but this way you can easily add more info from the server.